# python - construct method arguments using **kwargs?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create a method in my class which will let me use an arbitrarily sized set of columns to filter the results from a sqlachemy query. Something like:

```
def Find(self, **kwargs):

    f = self.db_session.filter(kwargs).first()
```

However, the `.filter()` method requires arguments in the format `table_name.column_name == value`. In this case the table name is always fixed, and I'm passing in the column_name/value as the key/value pair in the `kwargs` dictionary.

Is there a way I'm not seeing to manipulate the dictionary passed through in the `Find()` method to input the arguments to `filter()` in the correct format?

Answer (score 1):

`filter()` actually takes positional args. The `table_name.column_name == value` *expression* returns an object (due to overloading of the `__eq__` method by sqlalchemy) which represents the equality condition, and is then passed to `filter()` without a keyword argument name (note the lack of any *single* `=` in the parameters you'd be passing normally).

Thus, you can use `Find(self, *args)` and then call `.filter(*args)` and you'll be able to invoke `Find` just how you'd invoke `filter()`.

```
def Find(self, **kwargs):
    f = self.db_session.filter(kwargs).first()
    #...


# invoke as foo.Find(table_name.column_name == value, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy's query object already has a `filter_by()` method that takes keyword arguments, mapping column names to the values they must be equal to.